# Mouse cursor inverted on 2-in-1 laptop

Tags: display, mouse, cursor

I’ve got this pretty crappy chinese 2-in-1 laptop from ALLDOCUBE that has a recurring problem when trying to install any kind of Ubuntu on it. The screen is displayed sideways in the beginning and I managed to get that fixed with `xrandr`. After I’m done rotating it though, the cursor on the screen looks inverted and goes the opposite way when I use the trackpad. The machine registers the input in the right place but the cursor is displayed in the symmetrical opposite to it. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: The image is sideways but you can see that the cursor is inverted.]

P.S: I’m using Ubuntu 23.04 and sorry for the bad camera quality, I couldn’t get a screenshot.

Also, I've ported this question to Ubuntu Forums too.